# Django - How to query the most recent distinct rows before an effective date?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model full of effective dated rates. The notable fields on these rates are `name`, `type`, `effective_date`, and `rate`.

I need to be able to filter the modifier rates to get only rates of a certain type and before a certain date.

```
ModifierRate.objects.filter(
                type=settings.MODIFIER_RATE_TYPES_TAX,
                effective_date__lte=date)
```

That query may return rates with the same `name` and `type` so I need them to be distinct on those two fields.

```
.distinct('name', 'type')`
```

However, if there is a duplicate name and type I need the most recent one.

```
.order_by('-effective_date')
```

After all that I need to aggregate Sum the rates on those objects.

```
.aggregate(rate__sum=Coalesce(Sum('rate'), 0))['rate_sum']
```

If I try and smash all these things together I get

```
    raise NotImplementedError("aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.")
NotImplementedError: aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.
```

I've been googling for awhile and there are many similar questions that make use of `values_list` and `annotate` but I don't think that's what I want.

How do I get the sum of the rates before a certain date that are distinct on fields name and type where the most recent distinct rate is used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use django [Subquery expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), read the link for details.

```
most_recent = ModifierRate.objects.filter(
    name=OuterRef('name'), 
).order_by(
    '-effective_date'
)

result = ModifierRate.objects.filter(
    type=settings.MODIFIER_RATE_TYPES_TAX,
    effective_date__lte=date
    pk=Subquery(most_recent.values('pk')[:1])
).aggragate(
    rate__sum=Coalesce(Sum('rate'), 0)
)['rate_sum']
```

Comment: I don't this would remove duplicates on type and name would it? And how do I make sure that the duplicates being removed are the older ones?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and report back